Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc9w.so'
I just installed Tableau Server. One of my dashboards uses MYSQL databases. It needs an odbc connector to connect database and tableau. However, the dashboard is not showing.
My db uses MYSql 8.0.37. However, when I installed the .tar.gz from the MySQL page, the problem persists. Mysql instructed to use the 9.0.0 odbc driver in .deb version and 8.0.37 in .tar.gz version.
I've installed 9.0.0, however it gives this error in tableau dashboard: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc9w.so' : file not found.
When I check the folder, it is there.
I've tried installed both .tar and .deb. Both gives error.
Specs:
Tableau Server version 20233.24.0514.1218. - Ubuntu 22.04
mysql  Ver 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

This question has nothing to do with programming or software development, this is about installing and configuring components to connect two readily available applications. Depending on your environment, superuser or serverfault sister site of SO is the right place to ask this question, or go straight to mysql's support forum.
